# Tooltips (title="...") won't show in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, dom-events

I have an element with a `title` attribute (i.e., a tooltip), wrapped in some container:

```
<div id="foo">
    <input type="text" title="A tooltip" />
</div>
```

and I attach a `"mousemove"` event listener on the container and stop event propagation:

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener(
    'mousemove',
    function(e) { e.stopPropagation() },
    false
)
```

This combination of stopping propagation of "mousemoves" on the container now prevents the tooltip from showing up for the inner textbox, *in Firefox* 2 and upwards. I've tried FF 2[.0.0.20], 3[.0.11], and the latest 3.5 (Windows Server 2003, XP).

As a quick exercise, **Firefox** users can see this bug in action by running the following equivalent logic as above in your address bar:

```
javascript:void($('div.vote').mousemove(function(e){ e.stopPropagation() }))
```

Now mouseover any of the vote up, vote down, or star (favorites) icons for this question. The tooltips no longer appear. ***Again, in Firefox only***.

Does anyone have a workaround for this behavior/bug in Firefox? Has anyone else witnessed this?

**Update**: It appears Firefox uses "mouse stopped moving" to trigger tooltips in the browser chrome (eg back/forward buttons). See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82953. However I can't tell if this affects the DOM.

**Update**: It appears Firefox 10 was the last version exhibiting this behavior. Firefox 11.0 and onwards shows tooltips regardless of event propagation.

**Update**: Firefox 33(.1) no longer exhibits this behavior.

Comment: "The tooltip for the "Vote up" button no longer appears when you leave your mouse over it." False.

Comment: Ditto, doesn't happen for me.

Comment: @Ian, @altCognito: Which Firefox versions are you trying it with?

Comment: @Ian, @altCognito: what OS are you running?

Comment: Yeah, it very well could be a Firefox 3.5b4 thang, I certainly don't have that.

Comment: @altCognito: all FF versions are symptomatic. what are you running?

Comment: Crescent, I get the same behaviour you describe - FF 3.0.11 on Windows XP.

If I were to hazard a guess, I would suspect that FireFox uses mousemove to identify when/if to show the tooltip, and by stopping event propagation you stop it reaching the event handler that does this.

You may need to find another way to do what you want without stopping event propagation.

Comment: Yep, still happening on FF3.5 (stable). Pasting that line breaks the tooltip on the voteup arrow.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? This is a known behavior and, perhaps you don't really need to stop the Event's propagation and/or you can achieve the same result bypassing this. Can you give us some more detail on what you want?

Comment: This does happen for me in FF 3.5/Linux.

Comment: @Frankie: known behavior? I would love to see where this is documented. As to your question, the reason for stopping the event is buried deep in the application code. It has to do with needing to stop Virtual Earth (aka Bing) maps from dragging the map when a user (say) selects some text with the mouse in a dialog control (that is a child of the map).

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed this issue. I even tried propagating the event by hand to *only* the input box using this code:

```
<div id="foo" title="A tooltip 2"> <input title="A tooltip" type="text" id="bar"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener(
    'mouseover',
    function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var inputBox = document.getElementById('bar');
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evt.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window, e.detail, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, false, false, false, false, null, null);
            inputBox.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    },
    false
)
</script>
```

No dice. However, other mouse events, including mouseover, seem to work fine.

I believe this is a bug. Although it isn't listed in bugzilla, a search does seem to [indicate a correlation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=tooltip+event) between the event "mouseover" and tooltips.

You might download the latest [nightly build](http://www.mozilla.org/developer/#builds) of Firefox here and see if it still is there. If it is, [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi).

As an alternative, I would see if mouseover might give you the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I recently read that some firefox addOns (i.e. google toolbar) result in problems with the title-tooltips. Deactivate them and check if this solves your issue.