# Title attribute in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, title, attr

The title attribute on a particular HTML element is not displayed in my application if viewed in Firefox. There are multiple topics explaining this problem. I was unable to find a sollution that would fit my needs. So I ask if you can please help.

I have a number of divs lined up. On mouseover each of the div's should display a different value(title). The title attribute works fine in Chrome but I need something simillar for Firefox.

The title attribute is set dynamically from Javascript!

My Javascript:

```
dojo.connect(div, 'mousemove',rasterTimeDisplay);

function rasterTimeDisplay() {
dojo.attr(evt.target, 'title', "some new title");
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of your FF add-ons?

Comment: I am looking for a development sollution.

Comment: And we are still looking for a _real_ problem description.

Comment: which line of your invisible code should we focus on?

Comment: Isn't the question clear enough. I am looking for a practical advise or a concept suggestion...

Comment: adding your javascript might help :) Because it just works fine for me

Comment: Your code is still not complete(some variables are still not clear). However are you're tryng to add the `title` attribute when your mouse moves over the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to store the data to be displayed in another attribute ? Because you use javascript to feed your data-storage attribute, you can whatever you want.

For example, with jQuery :

```
//I feed my data-storage attribute
$("#my_div").attr('my-data', '<h1>my content to be displayed</h1>');
//And then i bind the hover event to toggle displaying of this data
$("#my_div").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).html($(this).attr('my-data'));
    },
    function(){
        $(this).html('');
    }
);
```

Or with standard JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById('my_div').my_data = '<h1>my content to be displayed</h1>';
document.getElementById('my_div').onmouseover = function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.my_data;
};
document.getElementById('my_div').onmouseoout = function(){
    this.innerHTML = '';
};
```

Comment: Can you somehow translate this to plain Javascript or Dojo

Comment: Edited, btw it wasn't a big deal, you could have it done by yourself. Programming is also cogitating a bit.

Comment: Also, if the answer was OK for you, please accept it. This could always be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i missunderstood you. However, you are trying to trigger the `title` attribute on hover? But the `title` attribute is already triggered by hover on default:

So if you just add the attribute to your desired element, you will get the extra information on hover.

```
var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
{
    titles[i].title = 'Hover information ' + i;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSFWT/1/)**

I you're interesting in the jQuery way to do this:

```
$('.title').attr('title', 'Hover information');
```

### Still doesn't work?

Step-1: First try to run your firefox client in [safe-mode](http://www.wikihow.com/Start-Firefox-in-Safe-Mode). Your problem might be solved now. If this is the case proceed to step-2. Else... Well i would suggest you to update your grapical driver or install a newer version.

Step-2: Disable your [Hardware Acceleration(AH)](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-gpu-rendering-in-mozilla-firefox-4-0-to-fix-font-problem/).

Check another answer about this here: https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/860902

---

Now if you just want a work around, to even let the oldest Firefox browsers support this. You can find one here: [Tooltips (title="...") won't show in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004826/tooltips-title-wont-show-in-firefox?rq=1)

---

I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: The title attribute is triggered but not shown only in firefox. I am looking for a trick or a workaroundto display the title attribute. Your fiddle doesn't work in my FF